# R aov Function - adjusting the alpha value..?

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I have always used the aov() function however Im wondering if there is a way or another function that allows the user to define the alpha value..?#

I'm assuming these tend to be the industry standard of 0.05....what if I wanted my aov function to yield a P-value based on 0.03...or 0.01 alpha values...?

Comment: Please study some statistics introductory book. The alpha error value has no impact on the p value.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the p-values of the object returned by `aov` with

```
pvalues <- summary(fit)[[1]][ , 5, drop = FALSE]
```

where `fit <- aov(...)`.

Now, you can compare the p-values with a certain alpha level, e.g., 0.01:

```
pvalues < 0.01
```

This returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks - I realised after posting that the determination is made by the actual P-value.